# I fail to make enum work correctly

Tags: c++, c

```
enum ENU{YES=0,NO,DONTKNOW};

void func(ENU e)
{
   int n;
   cout<<"1+1=";
   cin >> n;
   if(n==2)
     cout<<e.YES;
   else 
     cout<<e.NO;
   if(ischar(n))   
     cout<<e.DONTKNOW;
}
```

The error is always displayed. Because my program is too small and poor formed.

Comment: What error is always displayed?

Comment: What error?  And what is `ischar`?

Comment: Thank you, I just would like to know who cares about my post. I won't post again. Thank you.

Comment: So am I to understand you simply had no question but just wanted to see who would respond? If not, what is the error you're getting and what is your actual question?

Comment: Voted to close: in your earlier (closed duplicate) question I read "Thank you. There is no error in my real code, I can use enum, and enum examples are everywhere"

Comment: I removed all the extra fluff in your question because it had nothing to do with the question. It was unnecessary clutter. Other than that I voted to close it because there seems to be no real question. If you do have something to ask, clarify your question above. As you can surely see from the answers you have received so far, there are more than enough people providing you with excellent help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
    enum ENU {YES=0,NO,DONTKNOW};
    void func()
    {
       int n;
       cout<<"1+1=";
       cin >> n;

       if(ischar(n))   
         cout<< DONTKNOW;
       else if(n==2)
         cout<< YES;
       else 
         cout<< NO;
    }
```

There's no point in your example in passing the parameter ENU to func().
Also, you must test for ischar() first, to avoid entering any of the two other tests if it's not necessary.
Note that outputing your enum value with "cout<< YES;" for example, will not write "YES" to the console, but only its numeric value "0".

And a version which demonstrate the use of enum a little better:

```
void func()
{
   int n;
   cout<<"1+1=";
   cin >> n;
   ENU e = YES;

   if(ischar(n))   
     e = DONTKNOW;
   else if(n==2)
     e = YES;
   else 
     e = NO;

    cout << e << endl;
}
```

Remark: ischar() is probably not working as you would expect, as you're not giving it a character code.

Comment: The result of `ischar(n)` is undefined because `n` is not explicitly initialized and the input stream may not contain an integer. I.e., you should explicitly initialize `n` to a known value.

Comment: @ildjarn: _Potentially_ undefined.

Answer (score 5):

```
cout<<e.YES;
cout<<e.NO;
```

`e` is a variable. When you do `e.YES` you are trying to depict that `YES` is a member of `e`; which is [not correct](http://www.ideone.com/fizSU). I think you wanted

```
cout<<YES;
cout<<NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your use of enum is wrong! You can't write e.YES, you have to assign the value YES to variable 'e' in this way: e = YES and then you can display it.
And the display will be wrong, the cout will display it as its int value so that YES will be displayed as 0 and NO will be displayed as 1.